# Rpg call Java Constructor, error ClassDefNotFound on Exception handler

Tags: java, exception, constructor, ibm-midrange, rpgle

Error `NoClassDefFound` for Exception Handling in `Constructor`

this is Constructor in Java Code

```
public Class MyBook{
    String name;
    public MyBook(){
        try{
            name = "BookName";
        } catch(javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException se){}
    }
}
```

this is how i call MyBook in RPG

```
DBookObj   S   O   Class(*java:'com.abc.MyBook')
DMyBook   PR   O   ExtProc(*Java:'com.abc.MyBook':*Constructor)
C        EVAL  BookObj = MyBook()
```

.

```
  EVAL BookObj = MyBook()
```

give me error

```
NoClassDefFound: javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException
```

any solution ?
should i create a procedure specifically for this Exception Handler ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

need to download jar containing `javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException` [download jar from here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcomspringsourcejavaxxmlrpc110jar.htm) and set your `classpath`